# What is with the ground tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have several tags that are synonymous: [ground](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground), [grounding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grounding), [earthing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earthing). At the least we should roll `grounding` and `earthing` into the same tag. What do you think?

Comment: I've merged earthing and grounding, and left ground alone for now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Grounding* and *Earthing* are probably used interchangeably on this site and I agree they could be merged, possibly after looking at some statistics which I don't know how to do.

I think there's a big difference between questions about *ground* and questions about *grounding*. They are not synonyms, and if they are used as such, the questions should be re-tagged with the correct one.

Comment: If so I think grounding could be kept and earthing be merged with grounding. I also think we could keep ground as is.

Comment: Grounding, earthing yup more than likely used interchangeably here (or PE). Earth... Too often used instead of reference

Answer (score 1):

While most circuits have a "ground" reference, not everything is grounded to Earth. Thus they aren't *necessarily* synonymous.

Common bench power supplies may have both "ground" (-) and "Earth" (green) jacks, but coupling them may be optional, since they are not the same thing.

Maybe that's not enough to keep the tags separate though...